# Selenium :TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'executable_path'

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image]

I'm trying to run selenium chromedriver on heroku with:

```
def create_chromedriver(ua=False):
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = os.getenv('$HOME') or basedir+'/chromedriver.exe'
    FLASK_CONFIG = os.getenv('FLASK_CONFIG')

    if FLASK_CONFIG and FLASK_CONFIG == "production":
        CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = '/app/.chromedriver/bin/chromedriver'
        GOOGLE_CHROME_SHIM = os.getenv('$GOOGLE_CHROME_SHIM') or 'no path found'
        options.binary_location = '/app/.apt/usr/bin/google-chrome'

        options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
        options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
        options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
        options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
        options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")

    if ua:
        mobile_emulation =  {"deviceName": "Nexus 5"}
        options.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", mobile_emulation)

        options.add_argument("--headless")
        options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")

        capabilities = options.to_capabilities()


    return webdriver.Remote(executable_path=CHROMEDRIVER_PATH, command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',
                      desired_capabilities=options.to_capabilities())
```

when I run:

```
def some_long_calculation():
    driver = create_chromedriver('test')
    # driver = create_chromedriver()
    print(driver.capabilities['version'])

    driver.get("https://www.yahoo.com/")
```

I get the screenshot. The error log gives:

```
  2018-07-24T20:20:58.078553+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'executable_path'
```

How can I set the path to chromedriver here?

Comment: By here, I don't understand where? And where is this function `create_chromedriver`?

Comment: sorry, try this.

Comment: The `_init_()` for `Remote` does not accept `executable_path` as an argument. As made abundantly clear by the exception that occurred.

Comment: Got it, but how do you set the path to chromedriver to Remote then?